# How to compare 2 series which shows the date where the condition was True

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have 2 series dataframe :

```
macd_hist
Out[19]: 
Date
2015-06-16         NaN
2015-06-17         NaN
2015-06-18         NaN
2015-06-19         NaN
2015-06-22         NaN

2020-06-08    0.196930
2020-06-09    0.188928
2020-06-10    0.143611
2020-06-11    0.060999
2020-06-12    0.023659
Name: MACD_diff_12_26, Length: 1258, dtype: float64
```

and the second series:

```
macd_signal
Out[20]: 
Date
2015-06-16         NaN
2015-06-17         NaN
2015-06-18         NaN
2015-06-19         NaN
2015-06-22         NaN

2020-06-08    0.277051
2020-06-09    0.324283
2020-06-10    0.360186
2020-06-11    0.375435
2020-06-12    0.381350
Name: MACD_sign_12_26, Length: 1258, dtype: float64
```

To compare them i used the following code and the output is below:

```
macd_hist>macd_macd
Out[21]: 
Date
2015-06-16    False
2015-06-17    False
2015-06-18    False
2015-06-19    False
2015-06-22    False

2020-06-08    False
2020-06-09    False
2020-06-10    False
2020-06-11    False
2020-06-12    False
Length: 1258, dtype: bool
```

How can i get the list of dates where it is `True` instead of a list which contains True and False. So just a list of dates when the conditions was `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the result

```
s=macd_hist>macd_macd
l=s.index[s].tolist()
```

Comment: Could you please also include the code where the column with only `True` will be shown. Thanks